# How to properly handle focus

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

Lets say I have next layout:

```
Window
  UserControl
    UserControl
      UserControl
        Button
        GridControl
          GridCell
```

And lets say that GridCell currently has Keyboard focus. If a user clicks on button. a message is displayed to user to confirm action. No matter of what choice the user selected (Yes or No), a focus should return to a CurrentCell on GridControl. By default, after a user selected some option, a focus would return to Window (reported by Snoop). I would assume that a Button that was clicked would retain focus, but apparently not.

Handling of button Command is done in ViewModel (MVVM).

How do I return keyboard focus to a current cell in grid?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using UI-specific code-behind in MVVM, so why not just reset the focus in one of your dialog events? (Unloaded, VisibilityChanged, Button.Click, etc)

Comment: Hi Rachel, UI should not deal with business rules, which could be: IF condition, then show this dialog, else if another condition, show that dialog. This is related to business and must be part of VM. It is not only about message boxes, there could be whole dialog screens asking for some options. There could be a dialog, and in this dialog another dialog could be shown (like Details -> Advanced). That would require quite complex tracking of what was the last used focus element on each dialog. Is this the only way to preserve focus as it was before showing other dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably pretty safely work around this problem by setting `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="true"` on your button or if there are multiple buttons the parent element they are in (eg `StackPanel` or whatever).

There are a few potential issues with this if you are using `RoutedCommands`.  Basically `RoutedCommands` don't always work the way you expect them to inside of focus scopes.  It sounds like you are binding directly to a command on the View Model though so that shouldn't be a problem.  If you would like to read more about the `RoutedCommand` issue check [this code project article out](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38507/Using-the-WPF-FocusScope).

Here is what my sample code to verify this works looks like for your reference.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="25">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--You could also have the FocusManager.IsFocusScope set on the Border instead-->
        <Border Margin="0,0,0,15">
            <Button FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Click me!</Button>
        </Border>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MessageTextBox"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked, message: " + MessageTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Caleb. I have tried your solution, but it doesn't work. It stil puts focus on first user control inside main window, like it did before. I think the problem lies in the fact how I display message box. When a button is clicked, a command is executed on SomeViewModel, which sends a message that a messagebox should be displayed, with the the message to display. The global subscriber for this message is the main window, which then shows the message, and returns the execution to SomeViewModel.

Comment: Probably for the reason that main window is the owner of message box, it puts focus on first (and only) element in it (in my case its TabControl).

Comment: How does the main window show the message box and how does it return execution to the view model?

Comment: IIRC Each tab in the TabControl might be it's own focus scope, which might be complicating things.

Comment: I just tried my example in a TabControl and it still works so it looks like something else might be going on.

Comment: Can you upload the example, please, so I can see it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28809/discussion-between-caleb-vear-and-goran)

Comment: I am sorry, I had a call and needed to go immediatelly, so I didn't saw your invitation. Maybe tomorrow, if you have free time.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem actually was the Focus Scope itself. When pressing the Button (via Mouse or Keyboard - does not matter) it reset the focus to the first TextBox.

When removing the Focus Scope from the StackPanel, the Button did no longer lose it's focus when being pressed.

```
<StackPanel><!--FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">-->
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <Button>Click me!</Button>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```